# Can one class in java control object in another class?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class called `Factory`.  I intend to have that class publicly accessible so anyone can create and access the `factory`.  I want the factory to create and distribute `widgets`.  I only want the factory to be able to create `widgets`, not anyone in the public program space.  However, I'd like to have a method called `distribute()` that would give out a `widget` to the main program.  At that point the main program could access all the public methods of that `widget`.  It could also give it back to the factory if need be, thereby removing any public access to that object.

If this is possible, how does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is an inner class. By declaring the constructor of the inner class private, only the encapsulating class can access it! Then you create a factory method in the outer class to build the widget and distribute it. I've declared it `static` here, but that's not necessary, depending on your needs.

```
public class Factory {

  public static Widget buildWidget() {
    Widget widget = new Widget();
    return widget;
  }

  public class Widget {
    private Widget() { ... }
    public void someMethod() { ... }
  }
}
```

Note that in clean code your other concerns must be addressed by being careful about your referential integrity. To 'give back' the widget all other references to it must be released. Your Factory can certainly keep track of what widgets it's given out, but it's very hard to 'recall' widgets reliably.

Comment: Is there a way to have an inner class that is maintained in its own seperate file/class?  If my inner class get quite large, does it have to all be kept within that same file, or is there a way to break it out to another file for ease of management?

Comment: No; if you want class A to strictly control class B in that manner, you need to make it an inner class, which can only happen within that class. (Though you could write a thin wrapper, I suppose.) You should be careful of *why* you want to do these things, though. The motivation for doing it might more naturally inform another design entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing access control that changes over time ("It could also give it back to the factory if need be, therby removing any public access to that object.").  Java doesn't work that way.  All of the access qualifiers are statically checked, and remain constant for the entire lifetime of the program.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding (admittedly poor) phrasing of the question. If all references are released, no one can access that object, public methods or not. The OP may not quite understand how that works with Java, or be overstating the obvious, but that doesn't make it impossible.

Comment: It could easily be that I am misunderstanding the requirements.  I find access control within a program to be a silly feature of programming languages in general anyway....

Answer (score 0):

Place the widgets in the same package as the factory, and set the widget's constructors to have protected visibility. This will restrict the creation of objects to the factory.

For each widget, the access control can be partially implemented. You can keep a List in each of the widgets of Objects that are allowed to access, and only the factory can modify this list (protected visibility). For all public functions, you require the user to pass in an object that has been authorized to access the functions of the widget. You can return the object by passing the object that is authorized back to the factory so that it will remove the authorization.

You can pass a private object in the main class as authorization object - this will prevent other classes from using the widget. However, this doesn't prevent other classes from asking for authorization, though.

This is a bit flaky, since you may forgot to release the authorization and clutter the widget with "undead object" (not used anywhere else except for the access control list in the widget).

Comment: If by 'default' you mean 'protected', it will still allow any class in the same package to access the widget. Further, the control schema you suggest is incredibly taxing on a system, and error prone to boot.

Comment: @NathanielFord: The control schema is a way to force it to work, so the overhead is expected. And I admit I haven't thought everything through, so there might be many cases that I missed out. I agree that the visibility can be relaxed to `protected`.